# Laravel 5.1 - Get artisan arguments from internal call

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I do

when I run artisan `queue:work` or artisan `queue:listen` it runs the current commands with their corresponding Arguments. Now my question is, how can I Access those Arguments?

As you can see in the following Picture, the Arguments are there but I have no clue how to Access them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a project which follow a "[standard project structure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/structure)"

You must have a class in app/Console named Kernel which extends [Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.html), an example of how to implement it is as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //here you have to put your commands class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands(): void
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

so now let's create a new command, call it "print" and it will accept a parameter called text, here is the implementation :

```
<?

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class TestCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $signature = 'test {text}';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected $description = 'Test command.';

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info($this->argument('text'));
    }
}
```

as you can see, the new command accept a parameter called text and print it in console.

So to retrieve the parameter sent to an command call, you have to use the argument method in the follow way:

```
$commandInstance->argument('key_of_parameter');
```

To get more info read the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#arguments)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately that does not help me. I'm awaare of the default workflow. I however created my own Command class (which extends `\Illuminate\Console\Command` and in  my actual comment I extend this Command class. Now I want to access the command arguments from my Command class (not the command itself), `$this->argument()` does not work because `$this` is an instance of my command.